# Using API events to drive Journey entry with existing data?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We have a journey that we would like to be triggered in real-time from an external service, however there are some existing customers that also need to be included in this Journey (around 5K records) when it goes live.

Is there a way we can simply load the Data into the related Journey DE so when it goes live they will also be included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use automation studio SQL query to designate a source DE (or subset of that source) into a target DE which will be populated by both the API events, as well as the automation.

A DE is not "locked out" when populating from API, so a DE can aggregate data from a number of sources.

Disclaimer: you'll want to carefully consider duplication risk and ensuring you're not creating a convoluted journey entry process.  It might be just as simple to duplicate the journey and have the API run independently to reduce breakage risk & identifying error source.